# Why was Dr. Sivana unable to escape?

Tags: shazam-2019

Near the end of the film *Shazam!*, Thaddeus Sivana has been captured and imprisoned in what appears to be an ordinary cell (he is, after all, an ordinary human without the Eye). He desperately but unsuccessfully writes symbols on the walls of his cell, seemingly seeking to return to the Rock of Eternity and reclaim the Eye of Sin or some other source of power.

However, what prevents him from doing so? We have seen that the symbols worked for him before he had any intrinsic powers of his own, and he seemed to have them memorized.

Comment: This movie has [a lot of plot holes](https://screenrant.com/shazam-things-make-no-sense-film/).